# Python Script that used to work, is now getting automatically killed in Ubuntu

Tags: pandas, ubuntu, memory-management, out-of-memory, python-3.8

I was once able to run the below python script on my Ubuntu machine without the memory errors I was getting on windows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#create a pandas dataframe for each input file  
dfs1 = pd.read_csv('s1.csv', encoding='utf-8', names=list(range(0,107)),dtype='string', na_filter=False)
dfs2 = pd.read_csv('s2.csv', encoding='utf-8', names=list(range(0,107)),dtype='string', na_filter=False)
dfr  = pd.read_csv('r.csv' , encoding='utf-8', names=list(range(0,107)),dtype='string', na_filter=False)


#combine them into one dataframe
dfs12r = pd.concat([dfs1, dfs2, dfr],ignore_index=True)#withour ignore index the line numbers are not adjusted

# bow is "comming

wordlist=[]
for line in range(8052):
    for row in range(106) :
        #print(line,row,dfs12r[row][line])
        if dfs12r[row][line] not in wordlist :
            wordlist.append(dfs12r[row][line])
            
wordlist.sort()
#print(wordlist) 

print(len(wordlist)) #12350

dfBOW = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(dfs12r.index), len(wordlist))),dtype='int')

#create the dictionary
wordDict = dict.fromkeys(wordlist,'default')
counter=0
for word in wordlist :
    wordDict[word] = counter
    counter+=1

#print(wordDict)

#will start scanning every word from dfS12R and +1 the respective cell in dfBOW
for line in range(8052):
    for row in range(107):
        dfBOW[wordDict[dfs12r[row][line]]][line]+=1
```

Unfortunately, probably after some automatic Ubuntu updates I am now getting the simple message "KIlled", after trying to run the process without any further explanation.

Through simple print statements I know that the script is interrupted inside the for loop in the end.
I understand that I should be able to make the script more memory efficient, but I am also hoping for guidance on how to get Ubuntu able to run again the same script like they used to. (Through the TOP command I can see the all of my memory including the swap is being used while inside this loop)

Could paging have been disabled somehow after the updates? Any advice is welcome.

I still have 16GB of RAM, and use Ubuntu 20.04 (Specs are the same before and after the script stopped working). I use dual boot on the same SSD.
Below is the error I am getting from teh same script on windows :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\sharedfiles\Organised\WorkSpace\ptixiaki\github\ptixiaki\code\makingthedata\2.1 Approach (Same as 2 but turning all words to lowercase)\2.1_CSVtoDataframe\CSVtoBOW.py", line 60, in <module>
    dfBOW[wordDict[dfs12r[row][line]]][line]+=1

  File "D:\wandowsoftware\anaconda\envs\ptixiaki\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1143, in __setitem__
    self._maybe_update_cacher()

  File "D:\wandowsoftware\anaconda\envs\ptixiaki\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1279, in _maybe_update_cacher
    ref._maybe_cache_changed(cacher[0], self, inplace=inplace)

  File "D:\wandowsoftware\anaconda\envs\ptixiaki\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3950, in _maybe_cache_changed
    self._mgr.iset(loc, arraylike, inplace=inplace)

  File "D:\wandowsoftware\anaconda\envs\ptixiaki\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1141, in iset
    blk.delete(blk_locs)

  File "D:\wandowsoftware\anaconda\envs\ptixiaki\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 388, in delete
    self.values = np.delete(self.values, loc, 0)  # type: ignore[arg-type]

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in delete

  File "D:\wandowsoftware\anaconda\envs\ptixiaki\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 4555, in delete
    new = arr[tuple(slobj)]

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 501. MiB for an array with shape (12234, 10736) and data type int32
```